# Is there a way to activate the finishing moves?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What determines when you do a finishing move?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/35077/what-determines-when-you-do-a-finishing-move)

Can you activate the finishing moves at any time like when you stab your sword completely through someone or do these happen at random?