# How do I guarantee a Finishing Move animation?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What determines when you do a finishing move?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/35077/what-determines-when-you-do-a-finishing-move)

Is there any way I can guarantee that my next Killing Blow will trigger a Finishing Move Scene?

I am making a Skyrim Video and the new Bow Finishing Move scene does not proc that much.

Comment: This is not a Duplicate. I Know exactly what determines whether a finishing move will proc or not.  What i want to know is if there is any console command to make it proc ALWAYS, in EVERY KILLING BLOW.

Comment: I agree that your question is not a duplicate. To answer your question, try the mod [Killmove Plus](http://skyrim.nexusmods.com/downloads/file.php?id=9063), which should allow you to increase the chance of triggering the finishing move. Also, the console command '*set killmovechance to 200*' should also increase the chance of triggering the finishing move.

Comment: Correcting my comment above to mean "... the console command `set killmoverandom to 100` should allow you to increase the chance of triggering finishing moves". Also, I wrote a [more detailed answer to your question here](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/142518/4797).