# Is there any way to increase chances of a finishing move without commands or mods?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

Is there is a way to increase the chances without mods or commands?

Comment: @kotekzot I was going to say so too, but they just say "random" and don't answer the question about the actual chance, or how to make the chance 100%.

Comment: @SevenSidedDie Sounds like someone should post a better answer then.

Comment: @OrigamiRobot Those questions aren't *asking* how to increase the chance. Not a duplicate. They would have to be edited to make the question cover this question, which is frowned upon.

Comment: @Ryan There is a console variable `killmoverandom` (that defaults to `50`) that I can't find much documentation on, but appears to control the chance of killing moves triggering when an enemy is reduced to 0 health.

Comment: Thanks, but I am more interested in a way to change it without commands. I have searched around yet cannot find one.

Comment: @SevenSidedDie I think the question as it is covers this question just fine.  Also, look at the questions that have previously been duped to it.

Comment: @OrigamiRobot The other question has a highly-upvoted, accepted answer, that doesn't even mention the percentage chance or how to change it. A question that doesn't naturally attract an answer that covers the *core* of this question is, by definition, not a duplicate *question*. Duplicate *answers* aren't a close reason.

Comment: @SevenSidedDie I think that question _does_ naturally attract answers that covers this question, just nobody has bothered to post a good answer.  Lack of a good answer is never a reason to ask again.

Comment: @OrigamiRobot I have a hard time reading that with a straight face about a question with *15 answers* and a 27-upvote accepted answer. That statement strains credulity. That is not how this site works.

Comment: @OrigamiRobot May I remind you that [we have had this conversation before, and the consensus disagreed with your position](http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/7359/is-a-question-a-duplicate-just-because-it-asks-for-something-that-can-be-part-of).

Comment: @SevenSidedDie If I ask "What determines when I get a critical hit?", it also covers "How can I improve my critical hit chance?"  A good answer to the former will fully cover the latter.

Comment: @OrigamiRobot Yes, and that same argument in that meta ("To summarize, my biggest reasons for duping this question are: 1. It fits completely within the scope of the original question. 2. The answer can be easily and naturally updated to fully answer the newer question.") has -5 votes, while Sterno's has +21.

Comment: @SevenSidedDie Sterno's answer was also about the required knowledge being completely different, which is not the case here.  If you want to continue this, lets take it to chat.

Comment: @OrigamiRobot Sterno's answer is bolded at the bottom: We do not close a specific question as a duplicate of a more general question. We especially don't do that, then update the old question to *make* it more specific.

Comment: @OrigamiRobot Also note that my answer to that meta, which echoes what I've said here (a question that doesn't naturally attract the same answer is not a duplicate and cannot be closed as such), has 4 votes to your -5. This is a settled issue.

Comment: @SevenSidedDie If you _really_ want to reopen this question, reopen [the previous one](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/57425/how-do-i-guarantee-a-finishing-move-animation) instead and then reclose this one.

Comment: @OrigamiRobot That is indeed the correct duplicate. This just emphasises my point that sloppy duplicate votes are a problem.

Comment: Sloppy voting has been a problem since i joined. Often This community is to harsh and black/white. I have seen many legit questions get closed. Slightly different is still different and can be a world of change to someone in need of a specific answer.

Comment: Guys, If you find this question to close to the other one thats fine, but no answers on that post stated what I have asked. What would you then consider the right point of action for a question of this nature?

Comment: @RyanCallinan In the case of duplicate questions where the existing answers are not sufficient, try posting a comment on the question/answer stating why it is unsatisfactory and asking for more detail.  You chould also try offering a bounty on the question.

Comment: I agree with @Seven, Voting to reopen. [Duplicate information in answers (in part or in whole) does not automatically make **questions** duplicates. - orig. Sterno, Community Consensus](http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/a/7364/28182)

Answer (score 3):

Finishing / Kill moves are affected by the in-game variables,  'KillMoveRandom' (default: 50%), and 'DecapitationChance' (default: 40%) *and* various factors, some of which are:

- Kill Cameras will only be performed if killing the enemy will take the player out of the combat mode. Due to this, killing the last active/aggressive enemy will *often* trigger a finishing move / kill cam.  But this does not mean that only killing the last active/aggressive enemy will trigger a kill cam, e.g. killing an enemy while sneaking and remaining undetected will allow a Kill Camera, even if there are more enemies present.
- Your position relative to the enemy. For example, there is a one-handed sword stab-through-the-middle execution that will only play if you're standing behind a humanoid opponent. There are also finishing moves which require your enemy to have surrendered and fallen down to their hands and knees.

  - It should be noted that your steath state has an affect as well. Eg, you can cut throats with a dagger.
- The terrain: finishing moves appear to depend on relative elevation. While it's possible to enter into a finishing move animation on uneven terrain, it's far more likely to happen if both you and the enemy are standing on a flat, level surface.
- Other nearby obstacles: If the enemy NPC is too close to an object like a table, it may interrupt the animation and leaving you standing there until enough time has passed and the game gives you back control of your character.
- Chance: Some animations seem to play more often than others.
- Slow Time: Finishing moves will not trigger while under the effects of the dragon shout Slow Time.

<sup>Source: [UESP wiki, "Skyrim: Combat" talk page](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim_talk:Combat/Archive_1#New_finishing_moves_text) (edited to take into account the comments in reply to the original post) | [TES wiki, "Kill Camera" article](http://elderscrolls.wikia.com/wiki/Kill_Camera#Combat_conditions) (edited to explain further)</sup>
The only way to modify the in-game variables, 'KillMoveRandom', and 'DecapitationChance'  is by [using console commands or mods](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/142518/4797), which you said you can't or won't be using.

That leaves you to having to resort to workarounds that will take advantage of the other factors listed above to improve your chances of triggering a finishing move -  i.e. try going for stealth kills, make sure both you and your enemy are standing on even terrain, try to get the enemy out of obstacles that may interrupt the finishing move animation, don't use the Slow Time dragon shout.